# pandas, compute a value per group?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to go from `df` to `df2`
I'm grouping by `review_meta_id, age_bin` then calculate a `ctr` from `sum(click_count)/ sum(impression_count)`

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   review_meta_id  age_month  impression_count  click_count age_bin
0               3          4                10            3       1
1               3         10                 5            2       2
2               3         20                 5            3       3
3               3          8                 9            2       2
4               4          9                 9            5       2

In [70]: df2
Out[70]:
   review_meta_id       ctr  age_bin
0               3  0.300000        1
1               3  0.285714        2
2               3  0.600000        3
3               4  0.555556        2



import pandas as pd

bins = [0, 5, 15, 30]
labels = [1,2,3]

l = [dict(review_meta_id=3, age_month=4, impression_count=10, click_count=3), dict(review_meta_id=3, age_month=10, impression_count=5, click_count=2), dict(review_meta_id=3, age_month=20, impression_count=5, cli\
ck_count=3), dict(review_meta_id=3, age_month=8, impression_count=9, click_count=2), dict(review_meta_id=4, age_month=9, impression_count=9, click_count=5)]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df['age_bin'] = pd.cut(df['age_month'], bins=bins, labels=labels)


grouped = df.groupby(['review_meta_id', 'age_bin'])
```

Is there an elegant way of doing the following?

```
data = []
for name, group in grouped:
    ctr = group['click_count'].sum() / group['impression_count'].sum()
    review_meta_id, age_bin = name
    data.append(dict(review_meta_id=review_meta_id, ctr=ctr, age_bin=age_bin))


df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first aggregate goth columns by `sum`, then divide columns with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove columns and last convert `MultiIndex` to columns with remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['review_meta_id', 'age_bin'])[['click_count','impression_count']].sum()
df2['ctr'] = df2.pop('click_count') / df2.pop('impression_count')
df2 = df2.reset_index().dropna()
print (df2)
   review_meta_id age_bin       ctr
0               3       1  0.300000
1               3       2  0.285714
2               3       3  0.600000
4               4       2  0.555556
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) function after you grouping  the dataframe by `'review_meta_id', 'age_bin'` in order to calculate `'ctr'`, the result will be a pandas series in order to convert it to a dataframe we use reset_index() and provide `name='ctr'`, The name of the column corresponding to the Series values.

```
def divide_two_cols(df_sub):
    return df_sub['click_count'].sum() / float(df_sub['impression_count'].sum())

df2 = df.groupby(['review_meta_id', 'age_bin']).apply(divide_two_cols).reset_index(name='ctr')
new_df
```